# How to add ip based svn repository in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, svn, repository, xcode5

I am trying to add svn repository URL in **Xcode5** like this:

```
https://192.168.23.23:8912/svn/path/to/repo
```

but I am getting below error message:

**The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error-1012.)**

I am able to browse this url via Safari. What should I do now ?

Comment: That error code corresponds to `NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use address like http://base.server.com/. It is a bug in XCode and not resolved in XCode 5.1 DP also.

Comment: Thank you for informing. Is this bug filed on Apple's bug reporter?

Comment: I mean we need to use the address as reverse DNS order(com.companyname.something). Is this the right way to use the url.